# Cannot import name BlockBlobService from azure.storage.blob

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Although, there are many similar questions to the one I am asking, but non of them have helped me.

I am trying to store the file into my azure storage blob through directly through my system using the python script.

Here is the script I am using:

```
import os, uuid, sys
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService, PublicAccess

def run_sample():
    try:
        block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=<acc-name>, account_key=<acc-key>)

        # Create a file in Documents to test the upload and download.
        local_path=os.path.abspath(os.path.curdir)
        local_file_name =input("Enter file name to upload : ")
        full_path_to_file =os.path.join(local_path, local_file_name)

        print("Temp file = " + full_path_to_file)
        print("\nUploading to Blob storage as blob" + local_file_name)

        # Upload the created file, use local_file_name for the blob name
        container_name ='handwritten-text'
        block_blob_service.create_blob_from_path(container_name, local_file_name, full_path_to_file)

        # List the blobs in the container
        print("\nList blobs in the container")
        generator = block_blob_service.list_blobs(container_name)
        for blob in generator:
            print("\t Blob name: " + blob.name)
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


# Main method.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_sample()
```

Although, if I am running the script, I am getting the error as:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'BlockBlobService' from 'azure.storage.blob' (/home/nishant/anaconda3/envs/mera_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/__init__.py)
```

Here is the result of **pip freeze**:

```
azure-cognitiveservices-vision-computervision==0.6.0

azure-common==1.1.25

azure-core==1.8.0

azure-storage-blob==12.3.2
```

How can I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[v12 sdk](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-blob/) uses `BlobServiceClient` instead of `BlockBlobService`, if you want to use `BlockBlobService`  should use [v2 sdk](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-blob/2.1.0/). For v12 sdk usage, please refer to this [official doc](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-blob/).

So please change it to `from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, PublicAccess`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Actually, I am using ocr of microsoft to print the text of handwritten document  and I wanted to upload it on azure using script, that worked

Comment: But, when I am using ocr read on that image, I am getting the output of running status as well alomg with succeed status, and this is creating the problem in further manipulation, how can I resolve it?

Comment: @nipan09, could you please raise a new issue? And then let me know the new url?